# How to make image and text responsive next to each other on a background?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am completely new to bootstrap, have been working with it for like a week. 
I am currently working on a Christmas gift to my girlfriend and I am really stuck.

I want to place a picture and a short text (next to each other) on a background. 
The image look really much like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlrxu.png)
It's totally left positioned and there is text next to her. (There is also a bit of a place between the image and the text and also between the text and the end of the screen in the right. The picture starts in the left where the screen starts.)

I also want everything to be responsive ofc.

I tried everything but it never really worked and I wasted like 2 days on this issue.
I really can't make it alone! PLEASE HELP!!!

```css
.section_1 {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
}
.picture {
  content: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlrxu.png);
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
.text {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="section_1">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="picture">
        <div class="span2">
        </div>
        <div class="span10">
          <div class="text">
           <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: your code is missing closing div tags. like this we do not really see what happens and what you look for, can you set a bit of fake text with it ?

Comment: The .span classes have been removed since the introduction of Bootstrap 3. You might want to take a look at the 'new'  grid system here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid , use a combination of different .col-* classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap 3.x ".row-fluid" class has changed to ".row" and ".span*" classes have been changed to ".col-*". I have made few changes to your code and made it to behave as given in your image link, please click [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7irelQqcTYmWyUb364xP?p=preview) for plunker demo.

HTML file:

```
<section class="section_1">
<div class="container-fluid picture">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlrxu.png" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7 text"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS file:

```
.section_1 {
color: #fff;
background-color: #bdbdbd;}

.text {
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 300;
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
vertical-align: middle;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are meaning but here's what I think you mean.
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ack05umt/)

```
:)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to have something like this:
[NORMAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeciR.png)
And in mobile view something like this:
[MOBILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IQgl.png)

But many thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Please don't post comments as answers. You should edit your question and include the details there instead and then remove this answer.

Answer (score 0):

When using Bootstrap as in rraman's answer: because text can have more content that just one "Lorem ipsum," and height of the text div would become greater on smaller screens, your image, even though having class img-responsive (img-fluid), would be left with white space below. To remedy this problem you could use this css on img:

```css
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
object-fit: cover:
object-position: 50% 50%; //for always to show image center
```